# Are there benefits to allocating large data contiguously?

Tags: c++

In my program, I have the following arrays of double: a1, a2, ..., am; b1, b2, ..., bm; c1, c2, ..., cm; which are members of a class, all of length N, where m and N are known at run time. The reason I named them a, b, and, c is because they mean different things and that's how they are accessed outside the class. I wonder what's the best way to allocate memory for them. I was thinking:

1) Allocating everything in one big chunk. Something like.. double *ALL = new double[3*N*m] and then have a member function return a pointer to the requested part using pointer arithmetic.

2) Create 2D arrays A, B, and C of size m*N each.

3) Use std::vector? But since m is known at run time, then I need vector of vectors.

or does it not really matter what I use? I'm just wondering what's a good general practice.

Comment: Let me just point out that it's a design smell (not always bad) if you have arrays that mean "many different things".

Comment: @MarkB I think the OP means that the different arrays (`a_k` vs. `b_k` vs. `c_k`) mean different things (and I hope `a`, `b`, and `c` are just dummies for the purpose of this question), not that one array means different things in different circumstances.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right. And a, b, and c are dummy names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends significantly on how the data are used. If each array is used independently then the straightforward approach is either a number of named `vector`s of `vector`s.

If the arrays are used together where for example `a[i]` and `b[i]` are related and used together, separate arrays is not really a good approach because you'll keep accessing different areas of memory potentially causing a lot of cache misses. Instead you would want to aggregate the elements of `a` and `b` together into a `struct` or `class` and then have a single `vector` of those aggregates.

I don't see a big problem with allocating a big array and providing an appropriate interface to access the correct sets of elements. But please don't do this with `new` to manage your memory: Use `vector` even in this case: `std::vector<double> all(3*N*m);` However I'm not sure this buys you anything either so one of my other options may be more clear for the intention.

Answer (score 3):

If all three are linked in some way, if there is any relationship between a[i] and b[i], then they should all be stored together, ideally in a structure that names them with a meaningful and relevant name. This will be easier to understand for any future developer and ensures that the length of the array is always correct by default.

This is called design affordance, meaning that the structure of an object or interface lends itself to be used as intended by default. Just think how a programmer who had never seen the code before would interpret its purpose, the less ambiguity the better.

EDIT

Rereading I realize you might be asking about some kind of memory optimization (?) although it isn't clear. I'd still say use something like this, either an array of class pointers or structs depending on just how large N is.

Answer (score 2):

Use option 3, a vector of vectors. That will free you from worrying about memory management.

Then hide it behind an interface so you can change it if you feel the need.